# for loop error in python

Tags: python, for-loop

Why do i get an error when i go "if not any(line in website_list)" and why do i need the website variable? huhuhu help

When i am doing  "***if not any(line in website_list)***"  an error pops-up in that line, why do i need another variable 'website' in order to execute this? by the way i am a beginner.

I am creating a blocker app during working time.

```
import time
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime as dt

hosts_temp = "hosts" #temporary
hosts_path = r"C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"
redirect = "127.0.0.1"
website_list = np.array(["www.facebook.com", "facebook.com", "fb.com"])

while True:

    if dt(dt.now().year, dt.now().month, dt.now().day, 8) < dt.now() < dt(dt.now().year, dt.now().month, dt.now().day, 9):
        print("Working hours")
        with open(hosts_temp, "r+") as file:
            content = file.read()
            for debsite in website_list:
                if debsite in content:
                    pass 
                else:
                    file.write(redirect + " " + debsite + '\n')

    else:
        with open(hosts_temp, 'r+') as file:
            content = np.array(file.readlines())
            file.seek(0)
            for line in content:
                if not any(website in line for website in website_list): # I CAN'T UNDERSTAND THIS LINE
                # ^ cant understand this 
                    file.write(line)
            file.truncate()
        print("Fun hours")
    time.sleep(3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if not any(website in line for website in website_list)
```

This line means "if `website_list` does not contain any `website` such that `line` contains `website`"

`any` function accepts an iterable and checks that there is at least one element has truth value.

`website in line for website in website_list` is a generator for `True` / `False` series where `True` with index `idx` means that the `line` contains `website` on the index `idx`

`if not any(line in website_list)` does not work because `line in website_list` returns `True` or `False`. It also has different meaning, `line in website_list` means "`website_list` contains at least one element which is equal to `line`"